# Update not working in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have an array in my document which I want to update but so far I have failed to resolve it. Here `doctor` is the name of collection it's not an object.

```
doctor: {
   _id = ObjectID(571fb65678fcd63c29db423a),
   appointmentList : [
    {patientID:"123", date: "25 MARCH"},
    {patientID:"456", date: "26 MARCH"},
    {patientID:"789", date: "27 MARCH"},
    {patientID:"101112", date: "28 MARCH"}    
   ]
}
```

In this case I want to update the date for a **patientID = "123"**. For this I have created this query but this doesnt work

```
db.collection.update(
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("571fb65678fcd63c29db423a"),
        "appointmentList.patientID": "123" 
    }, 
    { 
        "$set": { 
            "appointmentList.$.date" : "XXXXX"
        }
    } 
);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
> db.collection.update(
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("571fb65678fcd63c29db423a"),
        "appointmentList.patientID": "123" 
    }, 
    { 
        "$set": { 
            "appointmentList.$.date" : "XXXXX"
        }
    } 
);
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
> db.collection.update(
{ 
    "_id" : "571fb65678fcd63c29db423a",
    "appointmentList.patientID": "123" 
}, 
{ 
    "$set": { 
        "appointmentList.$.date" : "XXXXX"
    }
}
```

);

Comment: I tried your code on my machine, and it worked just fine. Try maybe restarting mongodb? Or updating it?? Coz the code you run is valid, perhaps some misconfiguration or something like that. But the code is valid. Good luck!